# React: how to make a function work with a variable "getElementById"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

This is my first question here so I will try to explain what I'm trying to do the best I can.

Basicly I have a function the changes the style of an image, but I have 2 images and i didnt want to create 2 different functions for it, i wanted to recive a ID as a variable.

Images:

```
<a href="https://discord.gg/N8SDJGSzeS" target="_blank"><img className="img imgDiscord" id="discord" src={discord} onMouseEnter={mouseOver} /></a>
```

```
<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/15nLun4hYEI3l4Zf9MVMZkigGe9FD4Was5dDZLD3E6E8" target="_blank"><img className="img" src={rulesIcon} id="rules" onMouseOver={mouseOver}/></a>
```

Functions that are working:

```
function mouseOver(){
  document.getElementById("discord").style.height = "100px";
}

function mouseOver(){
  document.getElementById("rules").style.height = "100px";
}
```

Basicly i need to pass a string into the function to be able use only one function that work on both images.

For some reason doesnt work, it doesnt give any error but doesnt change the images height as well... and i have no idea why...

Thanks all for reading i really appreciate some help :P

But like i said i dont want to functions i wanted only one and i tried to do this =>

```
<a href="https://discord.gg/N8SDJGSzeS" target="_blank"><img className="img imgDiscord" id="discord" src={discord} onMouseEnter={mouseOver("discord")} /></a>
```

```
<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/15nLun4hYEI3l4Zf9MVMZkigGe9FD4Was5dDZLD3E6E8" target="_blank"><img className="img" src={rulesIcon} id="rules" onMouseOver={mouseOver("rules")}/></a>
```

```
function mouseOver(ids){
  document.getElementById(ids).style.height = "100px";
}
```

Comment: Try `onMouseOver={() => mouseOver("rules")}`. Also you can use the event arg to get the element with `currentTarget` instead of `document.getElementById`

Comment: `<a href="https://discord.gg/N8SDJGSzeS" target="_blank"><img className="img imgDiscord" id="discord" src={discord} onMouseEnter={()=>mouseOver("discord")} /></a>`

Comment: Don't  use `getElementById` within a  React app unless absolutely necessary. Use the passed [`event`](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers) or in more complex situations  assign  a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it (code goes inside the relevant component):

```
const handleMouseOver = height => event =< {
    event.currentTarget.style.height = height;
}

...

<a href="https://discord.gg/N8SDJGSzeS" target="_blank"><img className="img imgDiscord" id="discord" src={discord} onMouseEnter={handleMouseOver("100px"} /></a>

<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/15nLun4hYEI3l4Zf9MVMZkigGe9FD4Was5dDZLD3E6E8" target="_blank"><img className="img" src={rulesIcon} id="rules" onMouseOver={handleMouseOver("10px"}}/></a>
```